# make onmouseover change innerHTML content for containers AND nested elements

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, onmouseover

please see this jsBin http://jsbin.com/jimenohare/2/edit?html,output. My goal is to update the innerHTML of the `status` div with an `onmouseover` event on other divs. The problem is, the "status" div is always displaying that i am hovering over the body div, even when i hover over other divs nested inside of the body div. How can i make it so that it recognizes I am hovering over child divs inside the body div and not always display the `onmouseover` event for the body div? hope that makes sense.

```
<body id = "body" onmouseover = "statusSet( this )">
  <script>
    sets = [];//sets 000 - 999
    x = 0; y = 0; z = -1;
    for( var i = 0; i < 220; i++ ){
        z++;
        if( y == 9 ){
            x++; y = x - 1;
        }
        if( z == 10 ){
            y++; z = y;
        }
        sets.push( x + '' + y + '' + z );
    }
  </script>

  <div id = "sets">
    <script>
      var table = document.createElement( 'table' ), tr, td, row, cell;
      for( row = 0; row < 10; row++ ){
        tr = document.createElement( 'tr' );
        for( cell = 0; cell < 22; cell++ ){
          td = document.createElement( 'td' );
          tr.appendChild( td );
          td.id = 'n' + parseInt( row * 22 + cell );
          td.setAttribute( 'onmouseover', 'statusSet( this )' );
        }
        table.appendChild( tr );
      }
      document.getElementById( 'sets' ).appendChild( table );

      for( var i = 0; i < 220; i++ ){
        document.getElementById( 'n' + i ).innerHTML = sets[ i ];
        document.getElementById( 'n' + i ).id = 's' + sets[ i ];
      }
    </script>
  </div>

  <p id = "status">status bar</p>

  <script>
    function statusSet( element ){
      var elementId = element.id;
      var elementInner = document.getElementById( elementId ).innerHTML;

      if( elementId == 'body' ){
        document.getElementById( 'status' ).innerHTML = 'body';
      }
      else if( document.getElementById( elementId )
      .parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id == 'sets' ){
        document.getElementById( 'status' ).innerHTML = 'SET ' +   
        elementInner;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById( 'status' ).innerHTML =   
        elementId.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd listen for mouseover events on the body, and pass the event target to your status-setting function:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
  statusSet(e.target);
});
```

---

Here's a breakdown of how this works.

When you move your mouse over any element from the body, like a `<td>`, the `mouseover` event gets triggered on that element and every ancestor of it, including `<body>`. The originating `<td>` is passed along to each event handler in the `.target` property

Comment: when I add this line: `<body id = "body" onmouseover = "statusSet( this )">` the status is ALWAYS set to body. http://jsbin.com/jimenohare/2/edit?html,output

Comment: Because this is always the body element, you should pass the target instead, http://jsbin.com/cijuribuwa/1/

Comment: I don't understand how this works but it does...perfectly. Thanks.